# Deploy a CakePHP website fails. An apache2 config issue?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cakephp

I'm deploying a CakePHP (1.3.2) website for the first time. It was hosted on an older server. I received the project as a zip file. I managed to install it on my localhost and made the changes I needed.

Now I have to deploy it to a new server, but I face a problem.

The routing doesn't seem to work. I guess it's an `.htaccess` issue.

When I access the root folder, it redirects me to `/login` but then I have a 404:

> The requested URL /login was not found on this server.

My 3 main .htaccess files (`/`, `/app` and `/app/webroot`) are the following. (CakePHP is installed at the root of my virtual host)

**Root**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**/app**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

**/app/webroot**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

`mod_rewrite` seems to be activated on my server as it responds with this when I try to add it:

> Module rewrite already enabled

But when I try something simple like that on top of my root `.htaccess`, it doesn't do anything:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^.*$ test.php
</IfModule>
```

(I was following this guide: https://docs.bolt.cm/howto/making-sure-htaccess-works)

Among a lot of things, I also tried to add that to all my `.htaccess`:

> Option Indexes

But it didn't help.

Here is my website conf file too:

```
<VirtualHost xx.x.xx.xx:80>
ServerAdmin xxx@company.com
ServerName xxx.company.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/xxx.company.com

DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

php_value error_log "/var/log/apache2/xxx.company.com-phperror.log"
php_flag register_globals off

<Directory "/var/www/xxx.company.com">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride All
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/xxx.company.com-error.log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/xxx.company.com-access.log common

</VirtualHost>
```

(I added the Directory section that was not here in the first place)

---

After a lot of trials, I still haven't found anything that seems to solve my problem.

As I'm definitely not used to work on server side, It might be a simple thing that you will immediately spot. I hope so.

Thanks

Comment: Turn on debug mode in `app/config/core.php` so that you get actual error msg instead of the URL not found one.

Comment: Hey ADmad. Thank you for your answer. But I already have the debug mode set to 2: `Configure::write('debug', 2);`

Comment: Then the debug mode must be getting reset at some other place in your code. With debug one you would get a specific exception with details instead of the "URL not found"

Comment: Hi ADmad, thanks again. That's what I hoped too. But if, as I assume, the redirection in `.htaccess` is not working, then apache just sees a not existing folder, and never trigger any PHP, so no other error than this 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work. Here are the two mistakes I made:

- I had my document root set cake's root folder instead of the webroot folder. I added `/app/webroot` after `DocumentRoot /var/www/xxx.company.com` in my `.conf` file.
- Also, I was using apache's reload function, which is actually not properly reloading. Using `service apache2 restart` instead does the job.